# Wine on Erev Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, grapes-wine, drinking

Are there any sources saying that one should drink wine on Erev Yom Kippur, it being considered a Yom Tov?
(I’ve heard in chabad that Chassidim used to show up to Kol Nidrei drunk, as “a drunk cannot stand trial”; I’m wondering if there are any halachic sources discussing this.)

Answer (score 6):

The Mishna Brura ([OC 608:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.608?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.608.16&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)) mentions **not** to drink fine wine.

OU Kosher [writes](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/foods-one-eat-seuda-hamafsekes-last-meal-erev-yom-kippur/)

> Wine and other intoxicating beverages should **not** be served.

Comment: This is referring to the seudas hamafsekes, because wine may make it harder to fast. I’m wondering about the first meal which is modeled much more after a Yom Tov meal.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. First of all the objectives are to avoid over-eating/being too satisfied and avoid being a *baal keri*. Second there is no seudas mafsekes like on 9Av, there is a first meal of the day (say lunch), and a last meal before the fast. Now if you are asking specifically about lunch, you should ask a separate question.

Comment: The Poskim do refer to the last seudah as “seudas hamafsekes”, during which drinking wine is discouraged because of the reasons you mention. The question I asked is about Erev Yom Kippur in general.